# vuejs call method in another vuejs app (separate window)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two instances of the vuejs apps which are open on two separate browser windows.  I'd like to communicate between the two, passing simple data via methods.

With plain JS, you can declare a function on the page of Window B, and call it from Window A.

**Window A (Plain JS):**

```
var windowReference = null;
function openWindow() {
    windowReference = window.open("../path-to-win-b.html", "myWin");
}

function callFunctionInWindowB() {
    //Invoked by some element.onclick()
    windowReference.method();
}
```

**Window B (Plain JS):**

```
function method() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

How do I go about doing the same with vuejs?   I would have a separate instance of the App running on each window.

**Window A (VueJS):**

```
var app = new Vue({
    data() : {
       windowReference: null
    },
    methods : {
      openWindow() {
          this.windowReference = window.open("../route-to-window-b", "myWin");
      },
      callMethodInWindowB() {
          //Invoked by some element.onclick()
          //This line does not work
          this.windowReference.app.handleMethodCall();

          //These lines do work, but I don't think this is the way it's designed to be called:  I came up with this by examining the object model in Chrome's debugger.
          var app = this.windowReference.app;
          var vueComponent = app.__vue__;
          var childVueComponent = vueComponent.$children[0];
          childVueComponent.handleMethodCall(timeValue);
      }
    }
});
```

**Window B (VueJS):**

```
var app = new Vue({
    data() : {

    },
    methods : {
      handleMethodCall() {
         alert("Hello from window B");
      }
    }
});
```

Seems like I need to get handle of the vue app, and then find call the method.

The reason why I'm doing this is because windowB contains a video streamer, and I want to be able to use full-screen on windowB and use windowA on another monitor to input data.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you access `this.windowReference.app` since `app` is saved at the root of Window B?

Comment: I really, really don't recommend this. That being said, you can access a Vue instance's attributes, including its methods, through the variable where you've stored a reference to the Vue instance--in this case, the variable `app`. For instance, you can do `app.handleMethodCall()` in order to invoke the `handleMethodCall()` method of the Vue instance in Window B (from Window B).

Comment: I'd suggest using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or [window.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to communicate between windows/vue apps without needing to put references at the window level outside of closure.

Comment: Try to use vue-basement https://github.com/RashadSaleh/vuex-basement

Comment: when I try to call this.windowReference.app.handleMethodCall();
App.vue?26cd:255 Uncaught TypeError: app.handleMethodCall is not a function
    at VueComponent.callMethodInWindowB (App.vue?26cd:255).

In windowA, this.windowReference.app is returning an object, but cannot find the method "handleMethodCall()"

I edited the original post with my latest code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would reconmend that you use an external message broker application

You have a number of options but two of (what I) would consider the best are

redis https://redis.io/

It is a really fast in memory server that listens on an IP:PORT and it is also very simple to setup and use. It's main limitation is that is primary use is for small amounts of data i.e. key:value. This is also ideal if your on an internal network and have limited access to 3rd part solutions, or you just don't want to spend any money.

or

google Firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore
It offers more flexability in almost every way, it persists the data and any clients that are connected to it will update in real time. Ideally you would connect it via vuex then all your UI variables will update as data on firestore is changed. It can be free if you don't store much data, however it is more difficult to configure.

Once you have connected App A to a store and written data to it, you just get App B to poll the store to look for updates, with Firestore, you don't even have to poll, the data will be pushed into the App.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately I need the response to be instantaneous.  I'll have to pause the movie and get its current position as soon as the user clicks on "get" button.  Any asynchronous delay is not acceptable.